# How to fix `Request.GetNextPageLink` obsolete API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, controller, odata, deprecation-warning

When I code the following in my controller to make it compatible with OData pagination I encounter this warning:

> This method is obsolete; use the ODataProperties().NextLink property from the System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions or System.Web.OData.Extensions namespace.

```
return new PageResult<UserInfo>(
        results as IEnumerable<UserInfo>,
        Request.GetNextPageLink(),
        Request.GetInlineCount());
```

Answer (score 8):

Replace your code with this:

```
return new PageResult<UserInfo>(
                results as IEnumerable<UserInfo>,
                Request.ODataProperties().NextLink,
                Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount);
```

Do not forget to add:
`using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;`

Comment: In Net Core 2.1 you could find it in **Request.HttpContext.ODataFeature().NextLink** using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions